# ExtJs label text change

Tags: extjs

In ExtJs how to change label text dynamically
i.e
iam using like this
LabelError.innerText = "New password is required.";
LabelError.style.color = "red";

but its work only in ie and chrome but not in firefox

so how to change label text dynamically in all browsers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in the [label class docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.Label.html), the right way to do it is to call the function:

```
LabelError.setText('<span style="color:red">New password is required.</span>', false);
```

The `false` argument will prevent the html tags from being mangled by the function. Anyway, you can try to experiment with it.

Comment: thanks for ur replay,,,Its working very fine,  But still a problem in Mozilla (Not getting/display label in mozilla)